# Conversion from ttf to type 2 CID font (type 42 base font)

Tags: c++, unicode, ghostscript, postscript, truetype

I have ttf font files for Indian languages such as Tamil, Telugu, Malayalam, etc.
In order to access ttf files through a postscript program, I have to convert them to Type 2 CIDfont (Type 42 base font).
I tried online conversion (as well as utilities from GitHub) but unfortunately they all failed to convert.
Is there any conversion utility available?

Answer (score 3):

As I could not proceed further with my work due to font conversion issue, so I decided to take up conversion task by myself.

Since I was neither a font programmar nor a font designer, I had to learn the internals of `ttf` (Apple Computers) and
`Type 0` composite fonts (Adobe Corporation), just enough to write a conversion program, with the help of the following documents.

1. [Microsoft OpenType® Specification Version 1.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/)
2. [Fonts - TrueType Reference Manual - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/)
3. [PostScript Language Reference, third edition - Adobe Corporation (912 pages PDF, 7410K) Feb/1999](https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)
4. [The Type 42 Font Format Specification #5012 (28 pages PDF, 159k) 31/Jul/1998](https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/font-tech-notes/pdfs/5012.Type42_Spec.pdf)
5. [Adobe CMap and CID Font Files Specification #5014 (102 pages PDF, 541k) 11/Jun/1996 Version 1.0](https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/font-tech-notes/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf)

In order to benefit others, I have just released this conversion utility through **GitHub** on the following platforms.

1. **Windows 10 Platform** ([Github Public Repository for Conversion Utility on Windows 10](https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Win))

   Open up DOS command line and issue the following `clone` command to download source code:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Win
   ```

   Or execute the following `curl` command to download source code release in `zip` form:

   ```
   curl -o TTF2PostscriptCID-Win-3.0.zip -L https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Win/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.zip
   ```

   Or execute the following `wget` command to download source code release in `zip` form:

   ```
   wget -O TTF2PostscriptCID-Win-3.0.zip https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Win/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.zip
   ```
2. **Linux Platform** ([Github Public Repository for Conversion Utility on Linux](https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux))

   Issue the following `clone` command to download source code:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux
   ```

   Or execute the following `curl` command to download source code release in `tar` form:

   ```
   curl -o TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux-3.0.tar.gz -L https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.tar.gz
   ```

   Or execute the following `wget` command to download source code release in `tar` form:

   ```
   wget -O TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux-3.0.tar.gz https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.tar.gz
   ```

**Note:**

- This utility converts `ttf` file to `t42` file which is readily accessible through a postscript program. This conversion program also generates a `ps` file (a postscript program) which will display all the glyphs associated with the character set of `ttf` file.
- The two program files (`main.cpp` and `ttf.h`) are 100% portable. i.e. the contents of two files are same and identical across platforms.
- A `README` Document in Markdown format has been included with the release.
- This conversion software has been tested for the following [Indian Languages](https://fonts.google.com/noto/fonts) successfully whose number of Glyphs exceed 256 characters with horizontal writing.

  1. [Tamil](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Tamil)
  2. [Malayalam](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Malayalam)
  3. [Telugu](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Telugu)
  4. [Kannada](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Kannada)
  5. [Gujarati](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Gujarati)
  6. [Gurmukhi](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Gurmukhi) (Punjabi)
  7. [Oriya](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Oriya)
  8. [Bengali](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Bengali) (Assamese)
  9. [Devanagari](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Devanagari) (Sanskrit, Hindi and Marathi)

Comment: Great job!! That is really great!