# Ghostscript does not recognize the presence of CID-keyed font entry in Fontmap file

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, truetype

I have CID-keyed font `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` which has `534 Tamil and Latin` Glyphs and is stored in folder `F:\cidfonts`.
These Glyphs will be printed by a postscript program `NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps` in 5 pages.

`gswin64c.exe -sFONTPATH="F:\cidfonts" "F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps"`

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4233288 2759415 2938240 1653187 1 done.
Scanning F:\cidfonts for fonts... 4 files, 4 scanned, 0 new fonts.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/%rom%Resource/Font/No.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NotoSansTamil-Regular.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Courier for NotoSansTamil-Regular.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular... 4339800 3002661 2978640 1673735 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 4567512 3237790 2998840 1691005 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 4815424 3472868 3019040 1698294 1 done.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
GS>
```

`F:\cidfonts` folder contains the following 4 files:

1. Fontmap
2. Fontmap.GS
3. NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42
4. NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps

The contents of `Fontmap` file is:

```
%!
% See Fontmap.GS for the syntax of real Fontmap files.
%% Replace 1 (Fontmap.GS)
(Fontmap.GS) .runlibfile
```

The contents of `Fontmap.GS` file is:

```
/NotoSansTamil-Regular      (F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42)        ;
```

The issue is that Ghostscript does not recognize the CID-keyed font file `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` presence in `Fontmap.GS` file.
Ghostscript silently substitutes with `Courier` font.

Now, execute any of the following two commands supplying **CID font file** `t42` directly as command-line argument:

`gswin64c.exe -sFONTPATH="F:\cidfonts" "F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42" "F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps"`

**Or**

`gswin64c.exe "F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42" "F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps"`

```
 GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)
 Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
 see the file COPYING for details.
 Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4233288 2754279 3135728 1772705 1 done.
 Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 4299400 2961838 3539728 2140586 1 done.
 Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 4527112 3193692 3559928 2148739 1 done.
 >>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
 >>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
 >>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
 >>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
 >>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
 GS>
```

Now, Ghostscript displays all the 534 Glyphs available in the character set correctly. No substitution took place.

Ghostscript works as expected if CIDfont is **explicitly** specified through command line argument. Whereas it resorts to substitution whenever the CIDfont is specified **implicitly** through `Fontmap.GS`.

The question is how to instruct Ghostscript to look into `"F:\cidfonts"` for`Fontmap.GS` in order to fetch font `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` instead of substitution?

To put into simple words, how to configure Ghostscript to recognize CID-keyed Fonts?

Can anyone throw some light on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:**

Also refer [Conversion from ttf to type 2 CID font (type 42 base font)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931912/conversion-from-ttf-to-type-2-cid-font-type-42-base-font/74093991#74093991) which has relevance to this subject. This converts a `ttf` file into a`t42` file.

## This is an update based on comments from @KenS

I have already tried to configure `Resource/Init/cidfmap`  but it was not working (or I was making some mistake).

I have the `CIDSystemInfo`  dict in the cidfont `t42` as follows:

```
/CIDSystemInfo 3 dict dup begin
   /Registry (Adobe) def
   /Ordering (Identity) def
   /Supplement 0 def
end readonly def
```

I edited `Resource/Init/cidfmap` file with a single entry as follows:

```
/NotoSansTamil-Regular << /FileType /TrueType /Path (F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf) /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
```

The command was:

```
gswin64c.exe "F:/cidfonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps"

GPL Ghostscript 10.0.0 (2022-09-21)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4316928 2758434 2938112 1651719 1 done.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/%rom%Resource/Font/No.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NotoSansTamil-Regular.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Courier for NotoSansTamil-Regular.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular... 4383008 2962916 2958312 1668415 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 4469288 3166525 2978512 1693735 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 4696968 3390859 2998712 1700904 1 done.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

The command with `-s` switch generated the following output:

```
gswin64c.exe -sFONTPATH="F:\cidfonts" "F:/cidfonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps"

GPL Ghostscript 10.0.0 (2022-09-21)
Copyright (C) 2022 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 4347080 2778952 2938112 1651783 1 done.
Scanning F:\cidfonts for fonts... 3 files, 3 scanned, 1 new fonts.
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/%rom%Resource/Font/No.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NotoSansTamil-Regular.
Loading NotoSansTamil-Regular font from F:\cidfonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf... 4519672 2972708 3205656 1875933 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 4552984 3132356 3205656 1889803 1 done.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 4659464 3336098 3225856 1898588 1 done.
>>showpage, press <return> to continue<<
```

`F:\cidfonts` folder contained the following 3 files:

1. NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf
2. NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42
3. NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps

Observe that Ghostscript prefers `F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf` over `F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42`

Also note that I never set any environment variables related to Ghostscript such as **GS_LIB**, **GS_LIB_DEFAULT** or **GS_FONTPATH** under windows 10.

Comment: fontmap.GS maps Fonts, not CIDFonts so it won't have any effect at all with CIDFont usage.

Comment: @KenS thanks for the comments.  I have already tried to configure `Resource/Init/cidfmap`  but it was not working (or I was making some mistake). I have updated the post.

Comment: Without seeing your 'font' it is difficult to be certain, but from the small snippet provided it looks like what you have is not a CIDFont file at all, it is a PostScript program which reads font data (guessing at TrueType, from the name) and uses it to define a CIDFont in memory. So defining the FileType as 'TrueType' in cidfmap is incorrect, it is not a TrueType font, it is a PostScript program. There is a different form for defining PostScript CIDFonts in cidfmap documented here : https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#explicit-cidfont-substitution Format 3.

Comment: Yes, `t42` is an ascii file converted from `ttf` file. This file has both **CMap** and **CIDMap** along with `ttf` binaray data embedded as hex string (sftns array).
This file is accessable using postscript's `findfont` by NotoSansTamil-Regular.ps (or any other postscript program) and it works as long as `t42` is passed as an argument into ghostscript. The `Resource/Init/cidfmap` has sample (given in comments) which I used and it never mentioned about format 3. Your document link talks about format-3. 
I agree that format-2 is not suitable and incorrect.

Comment: I edited `Resource/Init/cidfmap` file with single entry in format-3  `/NotoSansTamil-Regular (F:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42) ;`
However Ghostscript still tries to substitute with courier font! This document further says `CID fonts must be placed in the '/Resource/CIDFont/' directory. They are not found using Font lookup on the search path or font path.` and I am looking into it.

Comment: @KenS please visit github where I published the conversion utility ([windows](https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Win) and [Linux](https://github.com/marmayogi/TTF2PostscriptCID-Linux)). You can readily generate `t42` and `ps` for Google's font `NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf`. This will be helpful for your inspection.

Comment: If you think you have found a bug then report it as such. I no longer visit Stack Overflow.

Comment: Already reported as a [bug](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=706037#c3) four weeks ago and awaiting for response.