# How to implement Unicode (UTF-8) support for a CID-keyed font (Adobe's Type 0 Composite font) converted from ttf?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ghostscript, postscript, truetype

This post is sequel to [Conversion from ttf to type 2 CID font (type 42 base font)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931912/conversion-from-ttf-to-type-2-cid-font-type-42-base-font)
It is futile to have a CID-Keyed font (containing`CIDMap` that enforces Identity Mapping i.e **Glyph index = CID**) without offering Unicode support inherently. Then, how to provide `UTF-8` support for such a CID-keyed font externally by an application software?

**Note:** The application program that uses the CID-keyed font can be written in C, C++, Postscript or any other language.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://davidnewall.com/software/utf8show/

Comment: @luserdroog thanks for the link. These postscript program do not support `CID` fonts. `README` clearly says that `The unicodeshow operator paints that array using the current font, which must have CharStrings or CharProcs defined.  Most fonts do. The current font cannot be a CID font.` This is because in CID fonts the `charstrings dict` is ignored but it is presence such as `/CharStrings 1 dict dup begin /.notdef 0 def end readonly def` is required. Similarly `Encoding` array presence is required in CID fonts such as `/Encoding [] readonly def` but is ignored totally.

Comment: There is an `Utf8decode` that decodes a UTF-8 encoded string producing an array of Unicode values. `Unicodeshow` paints the glyphs for that array using the current font. This will not work for Indian languages because only around 12% glyphs are alloted code space (unicode points) and rest do not have. Take glyph `ஸ்ரீ` which does not have a unicode point but consisting of `ஸ +  ் + ர + ீ` which will be decoded to four Unicode Points U+0BB8, U+0BCD, U+0BB0 and U+0BC0 respectively. 
`Unicodeshow` paints only glyphs corresponding to unicode points but never the actual glyph (ligature).

Answer (score 2):

The CID-keyed font `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` has been converted from [Google's Tamil ttf font](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Tamil).
You need this conversion because without this conversion, a postscript program can't access a truetype font!
Refer Post [Conversion from ttf to type 2 CID font (type 42 base font)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931912/conversion-from-ttf-to-type-2-cid-font-type-42-base-font) for conversion.

The CIDMap of `t42` font enforces an identity mapping as follows:

```
Character code 0 maps to Glyph index 0
Character code 1 maps to Glyph index 1
Character code 2 maps to Glyph index 2
......
......
Character code NumGlyphs-1 maps to Glyph index NumGlyphs-1
```

It is clearly evident that there is no Unicode involved in this mapping inherently.
To understand concretely, edit the following postscript program `tamil.ps` that accesses `t42` font through postscript's `findfont` operator.

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
/myNoTo {/NotoSansTamil-Regular findfont exch scalefont setfont} bind def
13 myNoTo
100 600 moveto 
% தமிழ் தங்களை வரவேற்கிறது!
<0019001d002a005e00030019004e00120030002200030024001f002f0024005b0012002a0020007a00aa> show
100 550 moveto 
% Tamil Welcomes You!
<0155017201aa019801a500030163018801a5017f01b101aa018801c20003016901b101cb00aa00b5> show
showpage
```

Issue the following Ghostscript command  to execute the postscript program `tamil.ps`.

- `gswin64c.exe "D:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42" "D:\cidfonts\tamil.ps` (on Windows Platform).
- `gs ~/cidfonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42 ~/cidfonts/tamil.ps` (on Linux Platform).

This will display two strings `தமிழ் தங்களை வரவேற்கிறது!` and `Tamil Welcomes You!` respectively in subsequent rows.

Note that the strings for `show` operator are in Hexadecimal format embedded within angular brackets. Operator `show` extracts 2 bytes at a time and maps this CID (16 bit value) to a Glyph.
For example, the first 4 Hex digits in the 1st string is `0019` whose decimal equivalent is `25`. This maps to glyph `த`.

In order to use this font `t42`, each string (created from character set of a `ttf`) should be converted into hexadecimal string by hand which is practically impossible and therefore this font becomes futile.

Now consider the following C++ code that generates a postscript program called `myNotoTamil.ps` that accesses the same `t42` font through postscript's `findfont` operator.

```
const short lcCharCodeBufSize = 200;    // Character Code buffer size.
char bufCharCode[lcCharCodeBufSize];    // Character Code buffer
FILE *fps = fopen ("D:\\cidfonts\\myNotoTamil.ps", "w");

fprintf (fps, "%%!PS-Adobe-3.0\n");
fprintf (fps, "/myNoTo {/NotoSansTamil-Regular findfont exch scalefont setfont} bind def\n");
fprintf (fps, "13 myNoTo\n");
fprintf (fps, "100 600 moveto\n");
fprintf (fps, u8"%% தமிழ் தங்களை வரவேற்கிறது!\n");
fprintf (fps, "<%s> show\n", strps(ELang::eTamil, EMyFont::eNoToSansTamil_Regular, u8"தமிழ் தங்களை வரவேற்கிறது!", bufCharCode, lcCharCodeBufSize));
fprintf (fps, "%% Tamil Welcomes You!\n");
fprintf (fps, "<%s> show\n", strps(ELang::eTamil, EMyFont::eNoToSansTamil_Regular, u8"Tamil Welcomes You!", bufCharCode, lcCharCodeBufSize));
fprintf (fps, "showpage\n");
fclose (fps);
```

Although the contents of `tamil.ps` and `myNotoTamil.ps` are same and identical, the difference in the production of those `ps` files is like difference between heaven and earth!
Observe that unlike `tamil.ps`(handmade Hexadecimal strings), the `myNotoTamil.ps` is generated by a C++ program which uses UTF-8 encoded strings directly hiding the hex strings completely. The function  **strps** produces hex strings from UTF-8 encoded strings which are the same and identical as the strings present in `tamil.ps`.

The futile `t42` font has suddenly become fruitful due to **strps** function's mapping ability from UTF-8 to CIDs (every 2 bytes in Hex strings maps to a CID)!

The `strps` function consults a mapping table `aNotoSansTamilMap` (implemented as a single dimensional array constructed with the help of `Unicode Blocks`) in order to map Unicode Points (extracted from UTF-8 encoded string) to Character Identifiers (CIDs).
The buffer `bufCharCode` used in `strps` function (4th parameter) passes out hex strings corresponding to UTF-8 encoded strings to Postscript's `show` operator.

In order to benefit others, I released this `UTF8Map` program through **GitHub** on the following platforms.

1. **Windows 10 Platform** ([Github Public Repository for UTF8Map Program on Windows 10](https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Win))

   Open up DOS command line and issue the following `clone` command to download source code:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Win
   ```

   Or execute the following `curl` command to download source code release in `zip` form:

   ```
   curl -o UTF8Map-Win-2.0.zip -L https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Win/archive/refs/tags/v2.0.zip
   ```

   Or execute the following `wget` command to download source code release in `zip` form:

   ```
   wget -O UTF8Map-Win-2.0.zip https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Win/archive/refs/tags/v2.0.zip
   ```
2. **Linux Platform** ([Github Public Repository for UTF8Map Program on Linux](https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Linux))

   Issue the following `clone` command to download source code:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Linux
   ```

   Or execute the following `curl` command to download source code release in `tar` form:

   ```
   curl -o UTF8Map-Linux-1.0.tar.gz -L https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Linux/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.tar.gz
   ```

   Or execute the following `wget` command to download source code release in `tar` form:

   ```
   wget -O UTF8Map-Linux-1.0.tar.gz https://github.com/marmayogi/UTF8Map-Linux/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.tar.gz
   ```

**Note:**

- This program uses `t42` file to generates a `ps` file (a postscript program) which will display the following in a single page:

  1. A welcome message in Tamil and English.
  2. List of Vowels (12 + 1 Glyphs). All of them are associated with Unicode Points.
  3. List of Consonants (18 + 6 = 24 Glyphs). No association of Unicode Points.
  4. List of combined glyphs (Combination of Vowels + Consonants) in 24 lines. Each line displays 12 glyphs. Out of 288 Glyphs, 24 are associated with Unicode Points and rest do not.
  5. List of Numbers in two lines. All 13 Glyphs for Tamil numbers are associated with Unicode Points.
  6. A foot Note.
- The two program files (`main.cpp` and `mapunicode.h`) are 100% portable. i.e. the contents of two files are same and identical across platforms.
- The two mapping tables `aNotoSansTamilMap` and `aLathaTamilMap` are given in `mapunicode.h` file.
- A `README` Document in Markdown format has been included with the release.
- This software has been tested for `t42` fonts converted from the following ttf files.

  1. [Google's Noto Tamil ttf](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Tamil)
  2. [Microsoft`s Latha Tamil ttf](https://gdfonts.com/latha-font/)