# How to center text on page in PostScript for CID-Keyed fonts converted from ttf related to Indian Languages?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, truetype

This post is sequel to [Conversion from ttf to type 2 CID font (type 42 base font)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931912/conversion-from-ttf-to-type-2-cid-font-type-42-base-font)

How to write a postscript program that centers a text generated from character set of `CID-Keyed` fonts on a page?

**Note:** `CID-Keyed` fonts are `Type 0 Composite` fonts which have been converted from `truetype` fonts applicable to Indian Languages. Without this conversion, no postscript program can access `truetype` fonts.

Thanks in advance.

### Added the following Demonstration Postscript Program.

The CID-keyed font `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` has been converted from [Google's Tamil ttf font](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Tamil).
Refer Post [Conversion from ttf to type 2 CID font (type 42 base font)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931912/conversion-from-ttf-to-type-2-cid-font-type-42-base-font) for conversion.

On Windows platform make sure that `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` file is available in folder `D:\cidfonts` (or any other drive of convenience).

On Linux platform, make sure that `NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42` file is available in folder `~/cidfonts`.

Write the following Postscript program `D:\cidfonts\center.ps` on Windows platform or `~/cidfonts/center.ps`on Linux platform as given below:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
/CTXT {dup stringwidth pop 3 -1 roll 2 copy lt {sub neg 2 div 4 -1 roll add 3 -1 roll} {pop pop 3 1 roll} ifelse  moveto show} bind def     % Center text. usage: X Y Width <Hex String> CTX. Example-1: 36 300 500 <Hex String> CTXT and Example-2: 36 300 500 (String) CTXT
/myNoTo {/NotoSansTamil-Regular findfont exch scalefont setfont} bind def   % usage: 15 myNoTo

13 myNoTo
% தமிழ் தங்களை வரவேற்கிறது!
0 500 594 <0155017201aa019801a500030163018801a5017f01b101aa018801c20003016901b101cb00aa> CTXT

% Tamil Welcomes You!
0 450 594 <0019001d002a005e00030019004e00120030002200030024001f002f0024005b0012002a0020007a00aa> CTXT
showpage
```

Issue the following Ghostscript command  to execute the postscript program `center.ps`.

- `gswin64c.exe "D:\cidfonts\NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42" "D:\cidfonts\center.ps` (on Windows Platform).
- `gs ~/cidfonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.t42 ~/cidfonts/center.ps` (on Linux Platform).

This will display two strings `தமிழ் தங்களை வரவேற்கிறது!` and `Tamil Welcomes You!` respectively centered in two subsequent rows of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering should work roughly the same regardless of the font's type.

The simple method is to use the `stringwidth` operator which returns the *x displacement* and *y displacement* for the string according to the current font. But this will only give you one axis for centering. A left-to-right or right-to-left font will return 0 for the y displacement.

```
/bounds gsave clippath [ pathbbox ] grestore def
/min_x bounds 0 get def
/max_x bounds 2 get def
/span_x max_x min_x sub def

%center along x axis, requires currentpoint to be set to determine y coord
/cshow {
  dup stringwidth pop span_x exch sub 2 div min_x add
  currentpoint exch pop moveto
  show
} def
```

If you need to center a string along both axes, you'll need to get a bounding box for the string using `(string) false charpath flattenpath pathbbox`.

Comment: Did you test this postscript program? Are you sure that operator `stringwidth` works with CID-Keyed fonts (converted from `ttf` related to Indian Languages) having glyphs exceed 256?

Comment: If `show` can render the string, then `stringwidth` can report the displacement. They use the same mechanism.

Comment: You are right! Moreover I added a postscript program `center.ps` in the post that demonstrates centering text produced from CID-Keyed font's character set.